# Multiproject solution publish isolated project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new at .NET and I am wondering which is the best way to achieve the following scenario.
I have a multiproject solution with a Main project which has references on the remaining projects.
I want to be able to publish and deploy isolated a project i.e Products.
Now if I publish Main project automatically all dependent projects are builted in the published folder, but if publish lets say Products at the same folder there are a lot of duplications. What is the correct approach to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: `"Products at the same folder there are a lot of duplications` No, if you need to publish Products only its better to publish along. When you publish main project everything should be bundles within one pack but again no point to publish Products within that directory of course and would be messy.

Comment: Yes but how can i handle the DLL's that are created ? I should manually copy and paste them at the main folder after I publish ?

Comment: Why does these 3 MVC projects have a reference even ?

Comment: As your `Products` is stand alone project and not using other reference so there shouldn't be any dlls you need to copy. It will completely fine if you publish in separate folder.

Comment: Lets say i publish in a seperate folder how the Main project will "read" the changes from that folder ?

Comment: No you got wrong here. As your `Main` containing the reference of `Products` so you must include `Products` while publishing `Main`. But you can publish `Products` seperately unless it doesn't having any reference. Point to note here, we always need to keep all reference together if they are linked each other.

Comment: You mean that if I want the Main project to be able to "read" the changes of Products , I have to publish again Main?

Comment: That's the deferent scenario though but yes if anything update in project you have to publish again, another way there would be to publish `project` seperately and copy dlls. However, this is not right approach and cause additional issue. Publish `Main` again would be expected way.

Comment: But there would be a significant issue while publish all together. Because, we usually have one main project along with class library. But in your scenario, you have all web app which would have same appsetting.json file which will be treated duplicate while publishing.

Comment: Is there an approach that i can achieve the scenario that I want. I mean to publish Products and my Main project to be able to "read" the changes ? without the need to publish Main

Comment: The answer would be no if you only use visual studio. On the other hand, the answer is yes if you use DevOps. It has that functionality to track the chnages autometically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252438/discussion-between-pikk-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).